# Process flow of an iOS Application

Tags: ios, ios5, process, workflow, bootstrapping

where can i find the whole process flow of an iPhone application, like there are bootstrap processes in web applications that define the flow of processes, calls to predefined hooks, and tells that in which orders functions would be called?
functions like:

```
viewDidLoad()
viewWillAppear()
viewDidAppear()
```

Searching for the process flow.

Comment: This will help you out: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/app-launch-sequence-ios/  Anything after that will depend entirely on your app.

Comment: @sosborn yeah thats actually what i wanted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this useful as well: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this image ,It shows complete life cycle of app

http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v121.jpg